# Rails 4 - Pass parameter to Nested Form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My `User` has_many `addresses`. I need two addresses: Home and Office. I have `address_type` column to indicate whether it's "Home" or "Office".

So I use nesting and build two times.

```
// controller
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  2.times { @user.addresses.build }
end

// view
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :addresses do |ff| %>
    <h2>Home Address</h2>
    ...
    <%= ff.hidden_field :address_type, value: "Home" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I want the **h2** and the **hidden field's value** to differ when building the form for Home and office.

Is there a way to pass parameter to that `build`? I want to make my `fields_for` looks like:

```
<% f.fields_for :addresses do |ff| %>
  <h2><%= the_param %> Address</h2>
  ...
  <%= ff.hidden_field :address_type, value: <%= the_param %> %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can pass parameters to `build`.  You could do something similar to this:

```
// controller
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  [ 'Home', 'Office' ].each { |type| @user.addresses.build(address_type: type) }
end
```

Then in your view, you could let the form builder pick up the value! for the hidden field.  And as far as the `h2` is concerned, you can access the current `address` object using `ff.object`.

```
// view
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% f.fields_for :addresses do |ff| %>
    <h2><%= ff.object.address_type %> Address</h2>
    ...
    <%= ff.hidden_field :address_type %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply! So the param `address_type` automatically translate to the field `address_type`?

Comment: I have tried your code by using `.build(label: type)`. But I got `Unknown attribute: label` Error. So I only be allowed to use column name for parameter?

Comment: It has to be an attribute in the model with a public setter.  so, yes it can be a column or a virtual attribute.

Comment: Thanks! I wished the parameter isn't constrained, but it will do for now.